# DRF validator to modify requested data

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger

from this serializer:

```
class SerializerExample(serializers.Serializer):
    attr = serializers.CharField()
    def validate(self, test_validate):
        attr = test_validate['attribute']
        if attr == 'whatever':
            test_validate['attribute'] = 'check 1'
        else:
            test_validate['attribute'] = 'check 2'
    
        return test_validate
```

Now, this is used in the endpoint:

```
@swagger_auto_schema(query_serializer=SerializerExample)
def create(self, request):
    return request_data
```

So, my question is, will be modifed request.data with the validated method or not?

Comment: do you want to modify request.data before validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, no, it's not going to modify the data.
And, in the other hand, If you could you shouldn't, because the official documentation says that you must returns the same data you receive.

This validation only check valid data and raise error if don't match a criteria.